# Is the mingw64-ucrt64 wuapi.h not as up-to-date to the Microsoft SDK version?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wuapi

I'm trying to move from Visual Studio to VSCodium for C++ Win32 programming but after installing the headers according to the [Visual Studio Getting Started Page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and compile the code it is saying that certain wuapi.h types don't exist (IUpdateSession3, IUpdateManager, IUpdateService). According to the [Win32 docs for wuapi.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/) from Microsoft, and the fact it compiles just fine in Vistual Studio I know they should.

Comparing the two header files in Windows SDK and ucrt64, the ucrt64's wuapi.h is much smaller and makes no references to the above types, along with a lot of the versions of each type (IUpdate2, IUpdate3, etc.) but Windows SDK version does have them.

Is this a case of the mingw64-urct64 headers not being fully implemented? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I will not be overly surprised if this is highly dependent on which version of mingw64 you're using, but my somewhat out-of-date version provided by MSYS2 also lacks these identifiers.

Comment: You're not missing anything, apart the official Windows SDK :-) Windows headers provided with mingw have been rewritten by hand and are notoriously out-of-sync, out of-date. They are either good enough for standard old Windows programming or unusable, depending on your context. Note the Windows SDK ships w/o Visual Studio.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm guessing I am stuck to using MSVC? Or can you still compile with gcc? My minimal amount of testing including files from the Windows SDK was unsuccessful and no where I've seen give clear includes needed or #defines (if any are needed).

Comment: You can compile with mingw/gcc but you'll have to add missing definitions by yourself. I don't think the Windows SDK headers are usable by gcc as is. I've always wondered why mingw doesn't use some parser/generator to sync headers, there may be legal reasons too...

Comment: [`IUpdateSession3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nn-wuapi-iupdatesession3) is at least as old as Windows 2000 SP3. If it's missing from MinGW that would indicate that MinGW hasn't seen any love in two decades, or that no one is actually using MinGW for anything serious.